# How can I show in the map the name or id of a Polygon as a label

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I'm trying to make a map with some markers and polygons in Flutter with the google maps package, and I want to display label for them, for the markers it was easy I can do it like this.

[image]

I want something similar for some polygons I'm going to display, how could I do this? The polygon class as opposed to the marker class does not count with a "infoWindow" variable, so how could I do it?

[image]

Something like this is what I'm looking after, the red zone being the polygon, and in the center a label to display the name of the polygon

This is how I create new polygons, zones is a list, where I store the information for all polygons.

```
Polygon(
        polygonId: PolygonId(zones[i].name),
        points: zones[i].points,
        fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
        strokeColor: Colors.black,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeWidth: 4,
      )
```

This is how I create new Markers, landmarks is a list where I store the information for all my markers

```
Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(landmarks[i].id),
          position: landmarks[i].point,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: landmarks[i].name,
          ))
```

Comment: what framework do you use?
Can you share a code sample ?

Comment: @LudoSchmidt I'm using flutter with the google maps package, im going to update my question